# Disable vectorized looping in FORTRAN?

Tags: loops, fortran, vectorization, gfortran

Is it possible to bypass loop vectorization in FORTRAN? I'm writing to F77 standards for a particular project, but the GNU gfortran compiles up through modern FORTRANs, such as F95. Does anyone know if certain FORTRAN standards avoided loop vectorization or if there are any flags/options in gfortran to turn this off?

UPDATE: So, I think the final solution to my specific problem has to "DO" with the FORTRAN DO loops not allowing the updating of the iteration variable. Mention of this can be found in @High Performance Mark's reply on this related thread... [Loop vectorization and how to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429655/205926)

[Into the FORT, RAN the noobs for shelter.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fortran standards are generally silent on how the language is to be implemented, leaving that to the compiler writers who are in a better position to determine the best, or good (and bad) options for implementation of the language's various features on whatever chip architecture(s) they are writing for.

What do you mean when you write that you want to bypass loop vectorisation ?  And in the next sentence suggest that this would be unavailable to FORTRAN77 programs ?  It is perfectly normal for a compiler for a modern CPU to generate vector instructions if the CPU is capable of obeying them.  This is true whatever version of the language the program is written in.

If you really don't want to generate vector instructions then you'll have to examine the gfortran documentation carefully -- it's not a compiler I use so I can't point you to specific options or flags.  You might want to look at its capabilities for architecture-specific code generation, paying particular attention to SSE level.

You might be able to coerce the compiler into not vectorising loops if all your loops are explicit (so no whole-array operations) and if you make your code hard to vectorise in other ways (dependencies between loop iterations for example).  But a good modern compiler, without interference, is going to try its damndest to vectorise loops for your own good.

It seems rather perverse to me to try to force the compiler to go against its nature, perhaps you could explain why you want to do that in more detail.

Comment: I suppose you're right that this is implementation specific. I had at one point thought that the newer FORTRANs were more apt to vectorize than prior ones, but I could be wrong. The existence of "dependencies between loop iterations" is exactly what I'm trying to preserve. The behavior of the compiled code is consistent with vectorization, and is thus killing the desired outcome.

Comment: But if you have written code with dependencies between loop iterations the compiler will not break those dependencies in its enthusiasm to vectorise loops.  The compiler will preserve the semantics of your code, unless it (the compiler that is) is broken.  Perhaps you could post some code.

Comment: And for optimization's sake, it's obviously a good thing, but in this case, it surely is not. In each loop iteration, some computation is performed that effects the next starting point of the loop.

Comment: Post some code.  The compiler will not break the semantics of your program, if you write loops with dependencies between iterations the compiler will implement them.  However, this does not mean that the compiler will not vectorise your loops, sometimes the compiler is able to analyse loop dependencies and vectorise them too.

Answer (score 1):

As High Performance Mark wrote, the compiler is free to select machine instructions to implement your source code as long as the results follow the rules of the language.   You should not be able to observe any difference in the output values as a result of loop vectorization ... you code should run faster.   So why do you care?

Sometimes differences can be observed across optimization levels, e.g., on some architectures registers have extra precision.

The place to look for these sorts of compiler optimizations is the gcc manual.  They are located there since they are common across the gcc compiler suite.

Answer (score 1):

With most modern compilers, the command-line option -O0 should turn off all optimisations, including loop vectorisation.

I have sometimes found that this causes bugs to apparently disappear.  However usually this means that there is something wrong with my code so if this sort of thing is happening to you then you have almost certainly written a buggy program.

It is theoretically possible but much less likely that there is a bug in the compiler, you can easily check this by compiling your code in another fortran compiler. (e.g. gfortran or g95).

Answer (score 1):

gfortran doesn't auto-vectorize unless you have set -O3 or -ftree-vectorize.  So it's easy to avoid vectorization.  You will probably need to read (skim) the gcc manual as well as the gfortran one.
Auto-vectorization has been a well-known feature of Fortran compilers for over 35 years, and even the Fortran 77 definition of DO loops was set with this in mind (and also in view of some known non-portable abuses of F66 standard).  You could not count on turning off vectorization as a way of making incorrect code work, although it might expose symptoms of incorrect code.