# Loop vectorization and how to avoid it

Tags: loops, fortran, vectorization

Loop vectorization is when all right-hand-side expressions are computed at the onset. I just discovered my loops are being vectorized (in FORTRAN 77... don't ask). I need my loop condition variable to be updated in each iteration, but how can I rewrite to work around this vectorization?

In a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429405/205926), I'm looking for a way to disable this optimization "feature" in FORTRAN specifically, but here I am looking for a more algorithmic solution to the general case.

Comment: I'm not sure that your posting two related questions is helping you get a clear answer to your underlying question.  It's confusing me !

Comment: My apologies. I figured opening the question to a general case and a general audience might be a good thing and that keeping the FORTRAN-specific details in the other thread for FORTRANnies might also be good. I'll cross-reference this thread from over there, though.

Comment: Are you talking about loop unrolling?

Comment: no loop-unrolling and vectorisation are not the same thing, though sometimes vectorisation is used for implementing loop-unrolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not what loop vectorisation means to me.  To me the phrase means that the compiler will generate code which can take advantage of any vector computation capabilities of the hardware.  On a simple Intel Xeon this might mean generating SSE4 instructions to simultaneously manipulate a few adjacent array elements together, on a Cray there may be much more available in terms of simultaneous execution of the same operation on vector registers.

How do you think that all the RHS expressions are 'computed at the onset' ?  I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Could you post some code to explain ?  If you mean that the number of trips through the loop is computed on entry to the first iteration, then that is correct.  That is a very useful feature when it comes to optimising code and not one most Fortran programs would benefit from avoiding.

If you are writing DO loops in Fortran updating the iteration variable is forbidden by the standard, and always has been so far as I recall.  Your compiler might let you get away with it but I wouldn't trust a Fortran program in which this happened.

Comment: All well-received, and yes, these are DO loops, so therein must be my problem! I suppose I could do an IF/THEN/GOTO combo instead.

Comment: If you post some code we may be able to help you unravel the dependencies.  If it's possible, it's always good to avoid conditionals, for optimisation if for nothing else.  And if you ever write a GOTO statement you have my permission to shoot yourself in the other foot too :-)